# How can I listen to the stdin through daemon thread

Tags: python, linux, shell, stdin

I have a RFID card connected to a USB port which sends data to stdin.

I would like to run a daemon thread to listen to the port, and gather the data from the USB port, analyze and perform some calculations and write it to a file, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to redirect the output of your RFID program to a [FIFO](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo) instead of `stdin`, and read it in your daemon.